# VS2012 not detecting folders in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I recently had a problem where VS2012 intellisense stopped working in my Workflow dll project. It didn't pick up any of my using classes or created variables. It only opened the intellisense if I used the keyboard shortcut.

Upon creating a new project to test the problem out I discovered that VS2012 didn't detect folders that I created in my solutions now for some reason. (tested it with fresh console app, dll, wf dll).

To fix the intellisense I tried all the recommend things (delete .suo file, clean rebuild, check if setting are enabled, reset settings.) none of them worked. I have no idea what to do for the folder problem or if they are related.

Is there any way to solve this?

The folder problem seems to be solved thanks to @Anton Sizikov. Any idea on the intellisense problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you describe steps to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: You mean, the Studio restarting was not helping?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I really don't know what the steps are. Last week before clock out time I had the intellisense problem. Today I decided to create a new project and see if it still does it and then I noticed that it doesn't pick up the folders. I created a console app. Added a folder. Built the app. Started typing using ConsoleApp.<insert folder name here> and it just didn't pick it up.

Comment: @Agat Tried restarting VS and it didn't help. Also restarted laptop multiple times just for the hell of it.

Comment: What's about any updates you've might set up?

Comment: @Agat I haven't downloaded any VS2012 updates lately that I know about. Is there anyway to check for certain? Log or something.

Comment: What's about Windows updates? I did not have such specific problem, but I did have some other ones caused by Windows Update. And solved those after next Updates again.

Comment: Last updates that were installed was on the 29th and then it still worked. I see it tried to install updates on the 1st (the friday it started) and failed.

Comment: Did you try deleting the `sdf` file rather than the `suo` - it's the `sdf` that's got the intellisense data.

Comment: @RogerRowland no I have not. Sorry where is this file located? Can't seem to find it.

Comment: If it exists, it should be in the same place as your `sln` file

Comment: None of my projects have a .sdf file in that directory, only .sln and suo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Activities folder is empty, so basically there is no class there, and as a result there is no such namespace defined.

What if you put a class inside it and define a namespace in it?

```
namespace ActivityLibrary2.Activities
{
   public class Test{}
}
```

Comment: Wow I feel pretty stupid right now. I did not know there needed to be anything in it as it was just a folder. That seemed to have solved the problem with the empty console app.

Comment: Folders is just a way to organize your files. Namespaces is what you define in code. You can even define multiple namespaces in one file.